# Exo Player Unity Plugin for Android for HLS Fragmented MP4 (fmp4)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, fmp4

I am trying to integrate the Google Exoplayer in Unity and I am a newbie in Unity. I worked with Easy Move Textures Plugin but it does not support HLS FMP4 and I want to develop the plugin. How should I proceed.??

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a Unity-Android plugin.
Exact details can be found in the Unity documentation and an example can be found here:
https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/generate-and-use-unity-plugins-3d1375c97f1b#.g3a9pfoai

Once you learn that you can create an Android app that wraps SimpleExoplayer.
You build a surface in Unity and pass it to SimpleExoplayer using setVideoSurface.

What is your target device (Oculus/Daydream/other)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try this out. But I have also found few solutions using the Google VR SDK and it uses exoplayer under the hood but the demo scenes mostly concentrate on the Day Dreams but I want to develop for Google Cardboard. I am trying to convert the demo scenes to work with Gaze-based input, If it works then I will share the project.